# Plot the tow data in one graph

Tags: plotting, functions, logarithmic-scale, scaling

```
data={{13, 679.52}, {19, 305.826}, {21, 242.22}, {26, 132.365}, {29,88.782}, {32, 57.2009}, 
    {37,24.5524}, {42, 8.82704}, {46,3.35573}, {48, 1.98509}, {52, 0.72441}, {54, 0.500693},          
    {58,0.362299}, {62, 0.324838}, {67, 0.243063}, {71, 0.15979}, {78,0.0589129}, {81, 0.0409279},    
     {88, 0.035613}, {95, 0.0513416}, {104,0.0885481}, {115, 0.152606}, {125, 0.193406}}
```

```
X = ListLogPlot[Apply[data & , data, {1}], PlotRange -> {{10, 130}, {0.02, 200}}, Joined -> True, 
Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"\[Theta]cm", "d\[Sigma]/d\[CapitalOmega](mb)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], PlotLegends -> Placed[{"(d\[Sigma]/d\[CapitalOmega])GP"}, 
{0.7, 0.65}], PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Medium]]

Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
B2 = {{{13.952, 364.7}, ErrorBar[36.4]}, {{19.13, 309.11},ErrorBar[30.9]}, {{21, 294.159}, 
 ErrorBar[29.4]}, {{26.2635, 237.26},ErrorBar[23.7]}, {{29.0713, 191.367},ErrorBar[19.1]}, 
 {{32.959, 151.82},ErrorBar[15.1]}, {{37.2786, 118.47}, ErrorBar[11.8]},{{42.246, 86.529}, 
 ErrorBar[8.6]}, {{46.1339, 67.5217},ErrorBar[6.7]}, {{48.9417, 39.7778},ErrorBar[3.9]}, {{52.6134, 
 32.0836},ErrorBar[3.2]}, {{54.7732, 24.2215},ErrorBar[2.4]}, {{58.2289, 14.0352},ErrorBar[1.4]}, 
 {{62.7646, 6.13975},ErrorBar[0.6]}, {{67.5162, 3.617},ErrorBar[0.36]}, {{71.8359, 2.20246}, 
  ErrorBar[0.22]}, {{78.0994, 1.92956},ErrorBar[0.19]}, {{81.987, 1.36348},ErrorBar[0.13]}, 
{{88.4665, 1.34112},ErrorBar[0.13]}, {{95.162, 1.34112},ErrorBar[0.13]}, {{104.665, 1.36348}, 
 ErrorBar[0.13]}, {{115.464, 0.979543},ErrorBar[0.09]}, {{125.616, 0.777114}, ErrorBar[0.55]}};

ErrorListPlot[B2, PlotRange -> {{10, 135}, {0.1, 400}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"\ 
 [Theta]cm", "d\[Sigma]/d\[CapitalOmega](mb)"},LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium],PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[{"(d\[Sigma]/d\[CapitalOmega])Exp"}, {.7, .65}],PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Medium], 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

Please I want to Show the two plots in one graph , When Y-Axis is logarithm scale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ErrorBarPlots` package is obsolete. Instead of it, you can use the built in functionality provided by `Around`, but you need your data in a different format.

From your `B2` and original `data`, first transform your data, then plot:

```
witherrs = B2 /. {{x_, y_}, ErrorBar[err_]} :> {x, Around[y, err]};

ListLogPlot[
  {data, witherrs}, 
  Joined -> {True, False},
  PlotRange -> {{10, 130}, {0.02, 400}}, Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"\[Theta]cm", "d\[Sigma]/d\[CapitalOmega](mb)"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium], 
  PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[{"(d\[Sigma]/d\[CapitalOmega])GP"}, {0.7, 0.65}], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Medium]
]
```

[image: scatter and line plot together]

Comment: thanks, but can you Plot or Show [X, B2] in one graph.. Please

Comment: @Mfafa See the edit